# Dynamically creating a Google Sheet from a chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, excel, google-chrome-extension, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

Basically have three mini-questions:

1. Can I use a Chrome extension to dynamically create a new Google Sheet?
2. If so, would I be able to format the cells of that sheet from the extension? (font color, cell width, etc)
3. Would I be able to download this sheet using the chrome.downloads API (this is kinda optional, but preferred)

Any help with those would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

1) Yes, at least two ways are available:

a) use drive API to create a new empty spreadsheet file, and sheet API to fill it with data and format. Access these APIS with XHR, drive API accepts JSON and XML, while sheet API works with XML only.

b) use google scripting functions to create, format and populate sheets, call google scripting functions from your extension with XHR. JSON is availble.

Tried both ways, both work.

2) First way requires good conversion to/from XML, since at least sheet API is unavailable in JSON. You can format cells with this API, but it will be rather complex. Second way, you do formatting with gscript objects such as cell and sheet, getting parameters and returning results in JSON.

3) Didn't try it, but have seen the examples for it.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution for this was to just create an HTML table and then convert it to an excel document. You can even format it by adding inline styles to the HTML table. There are plenty of scripts online that do the conversion, and I ended up using one of them.